# Google maps API geocoding not returning results

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm not sure why the following doesn't work. It doesn't enter the geocoder.geocode segment at all. All i want is to be able to receive a geocode for an address i enter without plotting it on any map.

```
var geocoder;
function codeAddress() {
var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    alert(results[0].geometry.location);

  } else {
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
  }
});
```

}

html code:

```
<div>
<input id="address" type="textbox" value="Sydney, NSW">
<input type="button" value="Encode" onclick="codeAddress()">
</div>
```

Comment: Code very much like that works for me. How about a live map that shows the problem or a jsfiddle?

Comment: I didn't initialize the geocoder. Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't initialize geocoder.  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();